# Can ghosts kill human according to hindu beliefs?

Tags: belief, ghosts

I saw [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2050/do-ghosts-and-spirits-exist-in-hindu-beliefs) question. But as we saw in films ghosts can move chairs, beat & kill human, they don't have legs....

Can ghosts kill human?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes

e.g. Brahma Rakshas can kill and eat humans. Does not mean any ghosts can kill humans, they need to be very powerful or have great tapas shakti while they were alive. No need to worry about your average ghost haunting and killing people.

Source - Kaishika Mahatmyam in Varaha Purana

Everyone who dies becomes a preta (ghost), but they leave earth once samskaras are done. Most ghosts who remain that way are souls who did not have samskaras done for them, or untimely death, or suicide.
 many don't care about killing humans. They just want to go to yama-loka so they can get their rewards or punishments according to karma, and then take on a new body according to desires.